# How can I extract the name of a directory from a full path in a batch file?

Tags: cmd

I want to rename files in a directory based on the name of containing directory, like

```
c:\bin\data01\foo.txt
```

to

```
c:\bin\data01\data01.txt
```

following the post [How to get folder path from file path with CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659647/how-to-get-folder-path-from-file-path-with-cmd) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need the parent directory name you can use something like the folowing which works for a maximum nesting level of 10.

```
ECHO %~p0>path.txt    
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 delims=\" %%G in (path.txt) DO (
IF NOT [%%G]==[] SET myVar=%%G
IF NOT [%%H]==[] SET myVar=%%H
IF NOT [%%I]==[] SET myVar=%%I
IF NOT [%%J]==[] SET myVar=%%J
IF NOT [%%K]==[] SET myVar=%%K
IF NOT [%%L]==[] SET myVar=%%L
IF NOT [%%M]==[] SET myVar=%%M
IF NOT [%%N]==[] SET myVar=%%N
IF NOT [%%O]==[] SET myVar=%%O
IF NOT [%%P]==[] SET myVar=%%P
)
DEL path.txt /F /Q
ECHO %myVar%
```

Based on Fraser Graham's answer

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a good Batch Reference that explains how you can do a for loop to tokenize a file path and pull out the directory name...

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true

If you have a file that contains a list of files, tmp.txt...

```
c:\temp\folder\foo.txt
```

you can parse those filenames in batch with...

```
for /F "delims=\ tokens=1,2,3" %%i in (tmp.txt) do call echo %%i %%k %%j
```

and that produces...

```
%%i = c: 
%%j = temp
%%k = folder
```

after that you can use the variable that matches the directory name as the filename in your copy. However, this that only works if all the paths are the same depth.