# How to get path from a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Following [How to get folder path from file path with CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659647/how-to-get-folder-path-from-file-path-with-cmd)

I want to strip the path (without the filename) from a variable. following the logic of the methods discussed above I would like to use batch bellow, which doesn't work. any takers? possible?

```
set cpp="C:\temp\lib.dll"
echo %cpp% 
"C:\temp\lib.dll"
echo %~dpcpp
"C:\temp\" > doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested: demo.bat

```
@echo off
echo "Setting cpp"
set cpp="C:\temp\lib.dll"

echo "Calling JustGetPath"
call :JustGetPath %cpp%

echo "Returning result"
echo %_RESULT%

echo "Quitting"
goto :eof

:JustGetPath
echo "  +JustGetPath( %1 )"
set _RESULT=%~dp1

echo "  -JustGetPath()"
GOTO :eof

:eof
```

Outputs the following when run:

```
"Setting cpp"
"Calling JustGetPath"
"  +JustGetPath( C:\temp\lib.dll )"
"  -JustGetPath()"
"Returning result"
C:\temp\
"Quitting"
```

See also: http://ss64.com/nt/call.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `for` command, like so:

```
set cpp="C:\temp\lib.dll" 

:: Print the full path and file name:
echo %cpp%  

:: Print just the path:
for %%P in (%cpp%) do echo %%~dpP
```

Comment: I tried this without success - admittedly it was on WINE on Linux so perhaps the interpreter hadn't been fully compatible with Microsoft Windows...

Comment: @PP: Hmmmm, this works on my XP, Windows 7, Server 2003 and Server 2008 boxes.

Comment: works on win7, i like this but learning the CALL way was a mind opener for me, so i give it the V