# Sublime Text 3 - Open CMD prompt at current or project directory (Windows)

Tags: cmd, sublimetext3

Solution for Sublime Text 2 is here [Sublime Text 2 - Open CMD prompt at current or project directory (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103028/sublime-text-2-open-cmd-prompt-at-current-or-project-directory-windows)
.But this script is not working in ST3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simpler solution is to install [SublimeREPL](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeREPL), there is a shell REPL. You can add keymap to your user config. However this open the shell inside Sublime.

If your prefer, the old script is still working. Instead of put them(`cmd.py` & `Context.sublime-menu`) in a `cmd` directory, you put them under `Cmd` directory, which should be capitalized.

And I simplified the script, here:

```
import os, sublime_plugin

class CmdCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        path, _ = os.path.split(self.view.file_name())
        os.chdir(path)
        os.system('cmd')
```

Comment: Tested in linux , when i open the terminal sublime hangs until i close the terminal. A quick search in google revealed that ´os.popen('cmd')´ will instead launch the terminal and allow me to use the terminal and sublime at the same time 7u7