# How can I open command line prompt from Sublime in windows7

Tags: windows, cmd, sublimetext3

I'v created a function in VIM named OpenCMD(), it used for open command line or terminal in VIM (And cd in the current file path)

```
func! OpenCMD()
    if has('win32')
        let com = '!cmd /c start cd '. expand('%:p:h')
    else
        let com = '!/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --working-directory=' . expand('%:p:h')
    endif
    silent execute com
endfunc
nmap cmd :call OpenCMD()
```

Now, I want to open command line and cd in the current file path in Sublime (sublime 3 beta). The function as the same as the `OpenCMD()`.

And I searched an question in stackover flow: [Sublime Text 2 - Open CMD prompt at current or project directory (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103028/sublime-text-2-open-cmd-prompt-at-current-or-project-directory-windows)

I did as the the first guy answered (Create cmd, cmd.py and Context.sublime-menu). But it cannot work, the cmd operation always disabled.

[image: cmd_in_sublime3]

Is there any way can get it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you save `cmd.py`? You might also want to check the console for errors.

Comment: Hi @skuroda, I think I found the problem. The file folder should be `CMD` instead of `cmd`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2 - Open CMD prompt at current or project directory (Windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103028/sublime-text-2-open-cmd-prompt-at-current-or-project-directory-windows)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The answer about [Sublime Text 2 - Open CMD prompt at current or project directory (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103028/sublime-text-2-open-cmd-prompt-at-current-or-project-directory-windows) is nearly correct.

Only one step (for me) has to be changed is the file name should be **uppercase**. Use `CMD` instead of `cmd`.

---

### My steps (Win7):

- Open folder `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages` or just click
  **Preferences** -> **Browser Packages..** in sublime-text-3 Beta
- Create a folder named `CMD` (**Uppercase**). The path of **CMD** should be `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\CMD`.
- Open the folder **CMD**, and create a file, named `cmd.py` (**lowercase**), paste the context as below:

```
import os, sublime_plugin
class CmdCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        file_name=self.view.file_name()
        path=file_name.split("\\")
        current_driver=path[0]
        path.pop()
        current_directory="\\".join(path)
        command= "cd "+current_directory+" & "+current_driver+" & start cmd"
        os.system(command)
```

- Create a file (again), named `Context.sublime-menu`. Add context as below:

```
[
     { "command": "cmd" }
]
```

- The Cmd function will work in **context menu** (right-click). For example:
  [image: Open_cmd_in_Sublime]

Of cause, if you want to open **command line** by command (by 'cmd' for example), you can add the following context into **Default (Windows).sublime-keymap** file. :

```
{ "keys": ["c", "m", "d"], "command": "cmd"}
```

You can open it from **Preferences** -> **Key Bindings - User**

Comment: It works with `Cmd` too, and if you see there's another file by default called `User`, so it seems that it only requires that the first letter is in uppercase.

Comment: As i favor typing instead of clicking: add `[
    { "caption": "Open CMD window in this folder", "command": "cmd" },
]` to a file called `cmd.sublime-commands` in the CMD directory to be able to use the command palette.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked but can't understand the background process that's making it work!

Comment: I wouldn't use the command keys 'cmd' like that, it prevents you from entering those three letters in the editor.

Comment: This flat out doesn't work.  I think it's missing a major caveat - Python must be installed?

Answer (score 12):

You can install **Terminal** package in Sublime text 3 using the following steps.

1. Click on **Package Control** in  **Preferences**.
2. Select **Install Package**.
3. Search "Terminal" in the packages list then install it.

Now when you right click on a file or folder you will see **Open Terminal Here** option

Comment: On my windows 10 machine, it uses PowerShell as default (not Command Prompt). So how can I enable Command Prompt as a default shell ?

Comment: I have had the solution for my problem, anyone care about it could be scroll down.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows i replace the command with:

```
command= "cmd /K cd "+current_directory
```

Comment: This should be: `command= "start cmd /K cd "+current_directory` otherwise it freezes sublime

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much @Marslo! But, I think we can improve the plugin a bit... (i"m on st3 beta, window 8)

```
import os
import sublime_plugin

class CmdCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        os.system("cd " + self.view.file_name() + " & start cmd")
```

Answer (score 0):

***[Bonus]***

As [@Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52878996/7890329) pointed out in his solution and my comment was below.

If you want activate **Command Prompt** instead **PowerShell**, you can edit the file `Preference > Package Settings > Terminal > Settings - Default` :

```
{
  
// Replace with your own path to cmder.exe
"terminal": "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe", // On my Windows 10 machine
"parameters": ["/START", "%CWD%"]

}
```

as be suggested as [here](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal#examples)