# How to Open CMD from Context menu and filename as output in cmd on Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, batch-file, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Actually I've done with this answer: [Marslo Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18656619/10023888), it's work fine open CMD from right click in sublime text 3.

but I've some question about this script,

```
import os, sublime_plugin
class CmdCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        file_name=self.view.file_name()
        path=file_name.split("\\")
        current_driver=path[0]
        path.pop()
        current_directory="\\".join(path)
        command= "cd "+current_directory+" & "+current_driver+" & start cmd"
        os.system(command)
```

how can I get the filename of current file when i open cmd from self file in cmd output?

basicly the opened cmd with script above is like this:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>
```

How to make a opened cmd output like this:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>php myfile.php
```

or:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>py myfile.py
```

so, I can run the script without typing "**php myfile.php**",

on another reason if my script is require arguments, when cmd is showing I just type the arguments, like this:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>php myfile.php IcanTypingArg1 IcanTypingArg2
```

and than just press enter to run this script.

Anyone can help me to solve this?

*I'm sorry for my english.*

Comment: Use [this](https://github.com/SmartManoj/CST3)  repo, press `Ctrl Alt D`