# Cant import sublime_plugin

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I cant import sublime_plugin.

This code worked yesterday:
`import sublime_plugin`
But when i came back today it doesn't work. My cmd.py file is inside Sublime Text 3\Packages\CMD. It gives me a ModuleNotFoundError. I use sublime text 3 and python 3. It also does not work from the command line.

I also tried to run it in VSCode which didn't work aswell.

Reinstalling sublime text 3 did not fix the problem.
After reinstalling Sublime multiple times it now seems to work.

So the whole code i have is:

```
import os
import sublime_plugin

class CmdCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        os.system("cd " + self.view.file_name() + " & start cmd")
```

It worked on the day i put it in the folder.

from this link: [How can I open command line prompt from Sublime in windows7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606682/how-can-i-open-command-line-prompt-from-sublime-in-windows7)

Edit: It doesn't work anymore.

Edit: **It works now (i had the plugin set up with a context menu, which on its own works (so it opens the cmd) its just that when i put a text command file in there that it broke). Thanks for all the help**

Comment: How are you running the code? What exactly do you mean that "it does not work from the command line"?

Comment: i mean if i use python cmd.py it wont work as well. It worked on the day i got that code. Also the code opens a command prompt in the current directory

Answer (score 0):

Try it in Spyder IDE, or try re installing it

-pip install sublime.

Comment: It still doesn't work even though i pip installed it.

Answer (score 0):

The only place it makes any sense to import the `sublime_plugin` module is in the code of a Sublime Text plugin and only the Sublime Text editor can execute one of its plugins.

It makes no sense to import the `sublime_plugin` module into code that will be run from the command line using a Python interpreter nor to try "to run it in VSCode".

I suggest you look at some Sublime Text plugin tutorials on the web and at the code of some simple plugins, something like the [Switch View in Group](https://github.com/adamchainz/SublimeSwitchViewInGroup) plugin is quite straightforward and easy to understand. If you have the time available you could watch some of OdatNurd's [Sublime Text Tutorials on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/c/OdatNurd/featured).