# Build System - Sublime Text 3

Tags: batch-file, build, cmd, sublimetext3

I have the following script called "build-bat.sublime-build":

```
{
  "cmd": "build.bat",
  "working_dir": "$project_path",
  "windows" : {
      "shell": true
  }
}
```

The script is in C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages

I can select the script in Tools/Build Systems/build-bat and then I run it via CTRL+B or via manually selecting it in Tools/Build

It happens exactly nothing. I don't see anything, I don't get any errors.

It should run a file named: build.bat in the current directory where the file that I am working on is placed. But that doesn't happen.

Why?

Comment: Open the console and see if there are any warnings or errors

Answer (score 4):

After adding a new build system to sublime text 3 you have to restart sublime text 3. After this the code above works.

Answer (score 4):

Create new build system and paste this:

```
{
    "file_patterns": ["*.bat", "*.cmd"],
    "selector": "source.Batch",
    // opens CMD window and runs with full features. Uncomment what you like
    // "shell_cmd": "start \"CMD from Sublime - ${file_name}\" call \"${file}\"",
    "cmd": "cmd /c start \"CMD from Sublime - ${file_name}\" call \"${file}\"",

    // works on Sublime Text console and you can't input anything
    // "cmd": "cmd /c \"${file}\""
}
```

Save it as **`Batch.sublime-build`** file. Tested in ST3 and ST4 versions.

Comment: Recommended for running in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename your `build.bat` to `make.bat` and choose the Make build system in ST. Just press `Ctrl+B` and ST will try to start `make` command and `make.bat` will be executed. The output will be showen in ST's console.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

---

It works with paths and files with *`whitespaces`* by spilting up the arguments with `"arg" ,` such as:

`[..., "/C", "START", "${file_path}", "${file_name}"]`

---

Paste this into your **`Batch.sublime-build`** file.

```
{
    "file_patterns": ["*.bat"],
    "selector": "source.Batch",
    // This runs the batch file in cmds' console
    "cmd": ["cmd", "/C", "START", "${file_path}", "${file_name}"]
}
```

Your batch file can then be run in the CMDs' CLI. I suppose it's possible to pass arguments also but this may be a starting point for you.

The above will run cmd.exe and run the code in its native console. This will accept your inputs of the **.bat** file.

---

Here's a build that can be saved as **BatchStConsole.sublime-build**

```
{
    "file_patterns": ["*.bat"],
    "selector": "source.Batch",
    // This outputs to Sublime Texts' console
    "cmd": ["cmd", "/C", "${file}"]
}
```

The above will run the code in Sublime Texts' console. This will not accept your inputs of the **.bat** file. But still useful for debugging as it passes any arguments like the native CLI but just no interaction.

---

Relevant help:

`START` https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/usage/build-systems.html

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "shell_cmd": "${file}",
  "working_dir": "$project_path",
  "windows" : {
      "shell": true
  }
}
```

then ctrl+ B works on any bat file after restarting sublime.