How to find the file with only file name?
I find a interesting function when using an exe program. But i don't know how to relaize this function.
The location of this program is in C:\tool\mfunction.exe. And a bat file is established in E:\data to call mfunction.exe. Write in bat file:
C:\tool\mfunction.exe data.txt

The data.txt is in E:\data.
Under the condition of ensuring that bat and txt files are in the same folder, can exe obtain the file path and read the file only through the file name of data.txt?
This exe program is compiled by C or matlab.
I tried to realize this funtion with matlab but fialed. I don't know how to get the bat file path.
in addition，this exe program only work when the bat and exe file is in the same folder. Therefore, this program may obtained the address of bat file by some means.

Make sure the batch file sets the working directory to it's own directory before calling your executable. I'm pretty sure there's nothing you can do in the executable to get the path of the launching batch file otherwise. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451668/bat-file-to-open-cmd-in-current-directory

One "obvious" workaround is to use the full path name of the data file, and not only of the executable. So perhaps fix the bat file and not the exe. :-)

@AlanBirtles   Thank you for inspiring me. I find a new method that setting the working path to the folder where the bat file is loacted: "cd /d %~dp0" . And then I can realize this function.

Add the e:\data folder to your PATH environment variable
