# DOS Batch Creating files with subfolders after reading from a list

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a txt file which has a list of filenames with directory structure. Example below (w/o the blank lines in between):

```
C:\createdocs\1.txt
C:\createdocs\2.txt
C:\createdocs\mydocs\3.txt
C:\createdocs\mysubdocs\4.txt
C:\createdocs\5.txt
```

I want to create a batch file which will read from this file one by one and will create the file with some dummy value ("this is a test file") at the path provided at each line. If the directory doesn't exist, create the directory as well. Is it possible using the batch scripts?

Answer (score 1):

In a cmd shell, you can use `for /f %var in (file.txt)` to process each line of the file sequentially. Then use the stuff [detailed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659647/how-to-get-folder-path-from-file-path-with-cmd) to process each line you've retrieved to extract the path. Then it's a simple matter of doing a `mkdir` followed by `echo 'this is a dummy file' > thefile`

Comment: Heh, doh. Thanks. fixed the link.