# How to find the location of the .bat script being called

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get folder path from file path with CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659647/how-to-get-folder-path-from-file-path-with-cmd)

I have a Windows .bat script that needs to execute a file that is in the same directory as the .bat file, but the .bat script can be called from any directory.  How do you find the location of the batch file itself, not just the current directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/659647/587279

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `%~dp0` to get the directory containing the `.bat` file.