# how can I get path to my `cmd file` when it runs as administrator?

Tags: windows-7, cmd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get folder path from file path with CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659647/how-to-get-folder-path-from-file-path-with-cmd)

How can I get path to my `cmd file` when it runs as administrator?

Problem is:

When I run my `cmd file` file as admin the windows sets the current directory as `c:/windows/system32`, not  `d:/my_script` for example, which is what I want. And my cmd script can't access files referenced by a short path.

Comment: @AndriyM, nothing same. Problem appears in runing script as admin.

Comment: I admit, that detail of your problem is something I cannot fathom at the moment. But both the question that I linked and the accepted answer are about how to obtain path to the batch/cmd file being executed, which seemed to me the essence of your question. @Werner Henze's answer is also about that, only it uses a somewhat unusual trick, possibly because Werner, too, didn't hear about `%~dp0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my bat-files I am using

```
echo %0%\..\
dir %0%\..\
```

which outputs

```
C:\tmp\t.bat\..\
...output of dir, directory listing...
```

Suprisingly (at least for me) a dir works this way. I would have expected this to be an invalid path because t.bat is a file and not a directory where you can go up using "..".