# Windows CMD script to get directory in which file exists

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a executable file `VSTO.exe`  & a `try.bat` file in one folder. I want to get the folder path of the bat file &  concat that path with `VSTO.exe`.

I have this script in my `try.bat`.

```
"%~fp0\VSTO.exe" /q
```

but it creates path: "`G:\test\try.bat\VSTO.exe"` . I want to get a path `"G:\test\VSTO.exe"`

can anyone tell me  how do i do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"%~dp0\VSTO.exe" /q
```

is the exact answer.

[How to get folder path from file path with CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659647/how-to-get-folder-path-from-file-path-with-cmd)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
SET CURDIR=%CD%
"%CURDIR%\VSTO.EXE" /q
```

The %CD% pseudo-variable expands to the current working directory.
Type SET /? to see other pseudo-variable (last page)

Comment: Do you have extensions enabled? (cmd /x to enable, cmd /y to disable)

Comment: yes. it is giving exception like 'not identified as internal or external command'

Comment: But that file "VSTO.EXE" is in the current directory where you execute the try.bat? And the current directory contains spaces? (Answer updated to account for directory with spaces)

Comment: If the executable is in the current directory, why not just say .\vsto.exe?