# Window batch file - removing the directory from a file path

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to search my code base for all **jscript** directories and then get a list of relative files within those directories using the following batch script...

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S jscripts') DO (
    CD %%G
    CD dev

    SET "currentDir=!cd!"
    IF NOT "!currentDir:~-1!"=="\" SET "currentDir=!currentDir!\"

    FOR /r %%F IN (*.js) DO (
        SET "relativePath=%%F"
        SET "relativePath=!relativePath:%currentDir%=!"

        ECHO !relativePath!
    )
)
```

It all works as expected until it gets to...

```
SET "relativePath=!relativePath:%currentDir%=!"
```

I can figure out what format I need to write this in to turn...

```
c:\dir\jscript\dev\file.js
```

into...

```
file.js
```

Please help!

---

**Additional information**

The directory setup is as follows

```
dir
    jscripts
        dev
            file.js
            file2.js
        live
            file.js
            file2.js


dir2
    jscripts
        dev
            file.js
            file2.js
        live
            file.js
            file2.js
```

I want find all **jscripts** directories, CD into them, get a list of all JS files **relative to the dev** directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem Where to start
pushd "c:\wherever\global2_root\"

rem Search .....\dev directories
for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /ad /s /b ^| findstr /e "\\dev"') do (
    rem change to that directory
    pushd "%%~fd"
    echo Now in !cd!
    rem process files inside directory
    for %%f in (*.js) do (
        echo %%f
    )
    rem return to previous directory
    popd
)
rem return to initial directory
popd

rem cleanup 
endlocal
```

Answer (score 5):

To extract the file name and extension from a variable containing a full path use `%~nx0` as in

```
set G=c:\dir\jscript\file.js
echo %~nxG
```

Quoting the following from [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659647/how-to-get-folder-path-from-file-path-with-cmd)

> ```
> %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
> %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
> %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
> %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
> %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
> %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
> %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
> %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
> %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
> %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
>
> The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:
> %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
> %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
> %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
> ```
>
> This is a copy paste from the "for /?" command on the prompt. Hope it
>   helps.
>
> #### Related
>
> [Top 10 DOS Batch tips (Yes, DOS Batch...)](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/20/top-10-dos-batch-tips-yes-dos-batch.aspx) shows
>   [batchparams.bat](http://gist.github.com/53402) (link to source as a gist):
>
> ```
> C:\Temp>batchparams.bat c:\windows\notepad.exe
> %~1     =      c:\windows\notepad.exe
> %~f1     =      c:\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.EXE
> %~d1     =      c:
> %~p1     =      \WINDOWS\
> %~n1     =      NOTEPAD
> %~x1     =      .EXE
> %~s1     =      c:\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.EXE
> %~a1     =      --a------
> %~t1     =      08/25/2005 01:50 AM
> %~z1     =      17920
> %~$PATHATH:1     =
> %~dp1     =      c:\WINDOWS\
> %~nx1     =      NOTEPAD.EXE
> %~dp$PATH:1     =      c:\WINDOWS\
> %~ftza1     =      --a------ 08/25/2005 01:50 AM 17920 c:\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.EXE
> ```