# Batch File - Get filename from directory and save as variable

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to read in a directory and get the filename from that directory.
I then want to save the filename as a variable and echo that filename out.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 for /F %%a in ('dir C:\Users\username\Documents\Training\Pentaho\Outputs\BatchFileOutput\ *.csv') do set FileName=%%a
 echo %FileName%
```

I am getting the following when command prompt runs:
"File not found
Directory"

Does anyone know how to resolve this or where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I think the only proble in your code is the _space_ in front of `*.csv`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Safer way of doing the same:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "yourDir=C:\Users\username\Documents\Training\Pentaho\Outputs\BatchFileOutput\"
set "yourExt=*.csv"
pushd %yourDir%
for %%a in (%yourExt%) do echo %%a
popd
endlocal
```

Sets both: Your directory and the extension you are searching for, Changes the directory to the one previously setted possibly including a `/d`rive change and then runs a loop over all files matching your extension and echo them out. To save **only the last one** you can use:

```
...do set fileName=%%a
echo %FileName%
```

Or to use them all within the loop you can use:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM Other things done here

do (
REM Do stuff with %%a here
Set filename=%%a
echo !filename!
echo !filename:~0,6!
echo !filename:a=b!
)
```

If you just want to echo them, you can just go for `echo %%a`. If you want to do other things like string-substitution or substrings as described in the comments you need DelayedExpansion as shown above. There are a lot of questions on SO as well.

Note that you can get different "parts" of the path of your file. Have a look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/659672/6707985) I always have a look on as well. Alternatively check the documentation for the for command typing `for /?` into the command-line.

Comment: thank you, this works! :) 

Could I not just use the following to get part of the filename (this does not seem to be working though?)

SET result=%%a:~0,6%

ECHO %result%

Comment: Nope. Reason is that these for loop parameter-variables are not thought to be used in that way. You could save it as variable and then using `DelayedExpansion` (<- Important stuff ;) ) do what you wanted to do. Note that you would always have to know which part of the string you want to get. Using delimiters and `for /f` or above shown way to get the filename are the usually safer way.

Comment: I have found a way to do it using the following code: 
for %%a in (*.%yourExt%) do set filename=%%a 
echo %filename%

However it then only echos out one filename when there are three filenames in the directory (I'm new to this)
I have looked into delayedexpansion and I'm not 100% sure how it could help in this case?

Comment: I might be inclined to use `setlocal`, `pushd`, `popd`, and `endlocal` rather than just `set` and `cd` in something like this, just to ensure that I'm not doing anything potentially catastrophic to the environment.

Comment: .... This was meant to write after the for-stuff... I was too lazy to type the rest of it.

Comment: In your example, `set "yourExt=*.csv"` and `(*.%yourExt%)` is incompatible, I believe? I think it will yield a wildcard called `*.*.csv`.  So it should just be `(%yourExt%)`, instead.

Comment: @Hunnicatt Good catch, fixed, thanks!